# Next JS - Using middleware to secure all pages and send user to default identity provider

Tags: next.js, middleware, next-auth

Is there any way to secure all pages using middleware in Next-js and ideally send user to default identity provider?

I am expecting that user should be authenticated to see any page in site which is build with next js.

Thanks